# Can a UIView access NSLayoutConstraints applied to it?

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Let's say you create a custom UIView as a library and some 3rd party adds it to their app and applies leading, trailing, top, and bottom NSLayoutConstraints between it and its superview. Is it possible for the custom UIView to access those constraints that were added to its superview and if so any idea how?

Comment: `self.superview.constraints`?!

Comment: Thanks for that! I had looked around for a property in the docs but should have looked closer at the methods instead.